# Card-IO is showing a picture of the CC on the confirmation screen

Tags: android, card.io

In Android, I am starting the latest version of a Card-IO activity using the following code:

---

Intent scanIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CardIOActivity.class);

scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_EXPIRY, true); // scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, true); // default: false scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, false); // default: false scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true); scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false); // scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, true); // scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true); scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, false); scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_RETURN_CARD_IMAGE, false); scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_CAPTURED_CARD_IMAGE, false);

startActivityForResult(scanIntent, 1);

---

I'm doing everything I can to not show the card image AND capture the expiry date manually as well, but not matter which properties i use, I can't suppress the card image from showing without setting EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION to false... which, since it suppress confirmation altogether, breaks the keyboard button. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no flag for not displaying captured image in ImageView its done internally.

Only way to do this is build library from [card.io-Android-source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) directly after editing [DataEntryActivity.java](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/blob/master/card.io/src/main/java/io/card/payment/DataEntryActivity.java)
 file at lines 141-152.

How to compile the source code is mentioned in its description.

Comment: Yeah, I've made the changes to source and need to submit a pull request to add this as a feature.

Comment: @Killingsworth Let me know if your pull request gets merged. Would love to implement that on my side too.